# Can I use Three.js in React Native for Desktop?

Tags: react-native, three.js, expo, react-three-fiber, react-native-windows

As I understand, React Three Fiber(R3F) supports React Native, but not sure if it works in the React Native for Desktop App. ([R3F](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/installation#react-native)).

They uses expo-gl library, and the offical document of expo says that it supports android, ios, and web.

[image]

Does this mean that I cannot use R3F in React Native for Desktop [(Windows, macOS)](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/)?

I've tried to initiate the React Native for Desktop app and tried to install three, R3F, and, expo-gl and run, but it didn't work.